# process builder not running to create campaign member

Tags: process-builder, campaign, campaign-member

I want to create Process builder which will create campaign member when contact is created and below conditions met

- Region = EMea
- Account Type = Partner
  Partner Category = Distributor
  Business Unit = Multi-Channel or Livesound
  Account Pricebook = EMEA LLC USD Dist. Price List
  Contact Object: Attribute = Live Sound Pricing

  but camapign member is not created ...whats the issue

logic i used for criteria    1 AND 2 AND 3 AND (4 OR 5) AND 6 AND 7
[image]

[image]

Comment: I recommended you debug the problem by using the information in [Troubleshoot Processes with Apex Debug Logs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.process_troubleshoot_debuglogs.htm&type=5).

Comment: this is better done in FLOW so you don't have to hardcode the CampaignId